# PostgreSQL : is max_worker_processes cpu bound?

Tags: postgresql, performance-tuning

I have seen a lot of PostgreSQL performance tuning blogs and companies like EDB suggesting putting **max_worker_processes** setting for PostgreSQL to the **number of CPUs** in the machine.

We are using a dedicated **PostgreSQL 13** VM in cloud with **16 vCPUs**. But the default setting of the Postgres **max_worker_processes=8**. Bases on default value What I was thinking Postgres will only go up to 8 vCPUs max and expected max CPU usage is somewhere around 50% until few days back we have got some connection spike which was actually bound to I/O overload yet CPU hit 95-99% during the spike.

So how the max_worker_processes is related to CPU? Does this have any impact if i leave it to default value of 8? Or is there any other ways to find an optimal value?

Comment: Every backend process (serving one connection) has one process available to it--itself.  So if you have as many connections as CPUs, then you can fill all the CPU without needing any extra worker processes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that you misunderstand `max_worker_processes`. This parameter does not limit the number of PostgreSQL back*end* processes (the server processes that belong to a database session), bu the number of custom back*ground* worker processes (for example, additional parallel worker processes).

If you don't use PostgreSQL extensions that create additional background worker processes (like `pg_prewarm` or `pg_timetable`), there is little use in increasing `max_worker_processes` if you don't also increase `max_parallel_workers`, the limit for parallel worker processes.

Setting these parameters as high as the number of CPU cores is fine if your workload is I/O bound or if you have a data warehouse that is running a single query at a time. With a CPU bound workload, I would set these parameters lower, so that you don't run the danger of overloading your CPU with parallel worker processes. Set the parameters high to optimize for response time and set them low to optimize for throughput, since parallel queries use more resources than single-threaded ones.

Comment: parallel worker is controlled by **max_parallel_workers**  and its taken from the pool of **max_worker_processes** right? so if i increase max_worker_processes without increasing parallel_workers would it be helpful to overall TPS or QPS? Just like you mentioned i don't want make pressure on CPU by too many parallel workers.

Comment: If you increase `max_worker_processes` without increasing `max_parallel_workers`, it won't do anything. There are backend processes (one per session, limited by `max_connections`), and in addition there are parallel worker processes to help with long-running statements. Only the latter are affected by the parameters you arked about.